# Access Modifiers within javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to access a function in javascript but it is saying that it is not declared. I am trying to set an access modifier and was wondering how I would do this within javascript.
Below is the function that I am trying to declare as public.

```
    <script language ="javascript" type ="text/javascript">
function PopupPicker(ctl, w, h) {
    var PopupWindow = null;
    settings = 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',location=no,directories=no, menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,dependent=no';
    PopupWindow = window.open(<%= getServerName.getserverName("/Quoteman/DatePicker.aspx?Ctl=") %>);
    PopupWindow.focus();
};
```

EDIT: This is where I am trying to call the function.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="DateInTxt" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox><asp:ImageButton
                    ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ImageUrl="~/icons/vwicn063.gif"
                    OnClientClick="PopupPicker('DateInTxt', 250, 250);" Width="21px" /></td>
```

Comment: Where is this script in relation to your HTML?

Comment: Below the </body> tag. I have also tried placing it in the <header> tag.

Comment: How are you trying to *use* the function? Where do you get the error?

Comment: I get the error when I try and call the function from a button.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors, and look at the actual page source to see what the input HTML looks like.

Comment: Do you mean the dynamic page when I'm de-bugging?

Comment: Is there an ending `</script>` tag that you are just omitting from your posted code?

Comment: yes, but there is another function below where I copied the snippet from which is why I haven't included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really are no access modifiers in JavaScript, as it is a nested scope language. Closures create the appearance of access modifiers where you can make certain functions available to objects at certain times.

Check out [JavaScript Closures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_ZvxMyFSCU) for a great visual explanation of how closures work in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question. now my next question is why is it not recognising my function?

Comment: Maybe start a new question that does not have any mention of access modifiers in it?